# Will stealing from a Pleading Vagrant give you the same relic as paying him?

Tags: slay-the-spire

When I meet a Pleading Vagrant I'm given two options: Offer Gold and receive a Relic, or rob him and receive both a Relic and a Curse. If I decide to rob him, will I get the same relic I would have gotten from paying him?

[image: Pleading Vagrant]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will get the same relic whether you pay the Pleading Vagrant or steal from him. I tested by choosing one option, quitting the game, reloading, then picking the other.

[image: Paying Vagrant]

[image: Stealing from Vagrant]